# why need theme,if page builder is there in wordpress

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes, theme-options

I am new into the arena of wordpress.I started learning about how to create website using wordpress.I am wondering if a page layout can be fully designed and customized by using a page builder plugin,why i need to use a theme.Isn't theme is used to define how my contents are going to be shown in pages ?

Answer (score 1):

Because is it a true s**t experience having to design every single page of your site. This can be ok if your site contains up to 10 pages which rarely change, but it is very bad ROI if you need to spend that much effort to publish a daily blog post.

In general the most important aspect of wordpress development is automation of admin tasks, and while there is no obvious and immediate contradiction between that and page builder, the reality is that most of the page builders existing right now are not coded well enough to support automation, and are lacking standardization which is a must for automation.

Anyway 4.8 is supposed to have a sort of page builder included in core.... will be interesting to see how well it work for all the various ways people use wordpress.

Comment: ok..thanks a lot ...understood the requirement of theme now ,irrespective of page builders.